# Postgres decrypting differences between v9 and v12 (pgcrypto 1.1 vs 1.3)

Tags: postgresql, psql, rijndael, pgcrypto

I'm forced to migrate an existing DB to AWS RDS. RDS's earliest version of Postgres is v12, while previously the database was running on v9.6 (with `pgcrypto v1.1` extension).

I moved the data using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`. Some of the data was encrypted, and some SQL functions were using `rijndael_decrypt` to decrypt that data, however this function is not available in pgcrypto v1.3 (which is the only version of the extension you can get in RDS psql12). Can I somehow decrypt the data using pgcrypto's `decrypt` function or anything else? Tried all availble algo/mode/padding combination for `decrypt` function, tried converting the key to `bytea` or using it as plain text, but all I'm getting is
`ERROR:  decrypt error: Data not a multiple of block size`.

EDIT:
Adding function definition from the DB:

```sql
postgres=# select pg_get_functiondef(oid) from pg_proc where proname = 'rijndael_decrypt';
                                pg_get_functiondef
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rijndael_decrypt(key text, input_text bytea)  +
  RETURNS text                                                                   +
  LANGUAGE c                                                                     +
  STRICT                                                                         +
 AS '/c_extensions/pg_rijndael/pg_rijndael', $function$rijndael_decrypt$function$+
```

Comment: decrypt the data in the olssystem to clear text and then insert the text encryted with the new encryptions

Comment: Sure if this is the last resort then I could do that I guess. Just wanted to confirm there's no way to do that in the new db only.

Comment: Offtopic: Version 12 will be EOL next year and you have to migrate again. Personally I would move at least to version 15.

Comment: Thank you, wasn't aware and that surely would have been hell to go over this again next year.

Comment: I am not seeing `rijndael_decrypt` inthe 9.6 version of [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/pgcrypto.html)? Is that maybe coming from somewhere else?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver found it here: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL9_6_STABLE/contrib/pgcrypto/rijndael.c#L451

Comment: rijndael_decrypt was compiled as a C function up until recently, but as far as I can tell it was never exposed to the user.  Can you show up the definition of the SQL function which made use of it in 9.6?

Comment: @jjanes I've edited the original question with the function definition, is that what you meant?

Comment: 1) That is a private function not meant to be used by end users. You have now found out why you should not use private functions. `psql (15.4, server 12.15)  select pg_get_functiondef(oid) from pg_proc where proname = 'rijndael_decrypt'; (0 rows)` 2) I am pretty sure what @jjanes is looking for is the functions mentioned here: *... SQL functions were using rijndael_decrypt ...*. Basically looking to see if one of the public functions as shown here [pgcrypto 12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/pgcrypto.html) can be used instead.

Comment: Though that is going to mean going back to your Postgres 9.6 instance and changing the SQL functions before doing the dump/restore.

Comment: An SQL function accessing a C function defined by pgcrypto should have `AS '$libdir/pgcrypto'`.  The definition you show looks like like it comes from some other package, and one which does not use the extension framework.  I think you will not have any luck getting RDS to support this unknown package.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver not gonna show the full function for now, but this is an example usage of if: 
```
ONLYIF(userdata.is_encrypted, rijndael_decrypt(enc_key, decode(rule, 'base64')), rule)::jsonb AS rule
```
Having both the encrypted value and the key I was able to execute that decryption directly from the command line and I got the proper result, however I cannot achieve the same result using any of the pgcrypto v1.3 functions. I dont need or want to keep that function in RDS, but I was hoping I could decrypt it in some other way.

Comment: @jjanes that's what I thought, and I don't really need to get it into RDS, was just hoping there's a way to decrypt that data using any other pgcrypto function, especially as we know the encyrpted value, the key and in theory the algorithm used (just not sure about the lenght of the key), but nothing seams to work, I was hoping I'm just missing some encoding/decoding or sth.

Answer (score 0):

Change the encryption and decryption methods to utilize PostgreSQL 12's pgp_sym_decrypt, which is available in pgcrypto 1.3. Make sure your application code has been adjusted appropriately and test the revised function.

Try this;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.decrypt_data(key text, encrypted_data bytea)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
  SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt(encrypted_data, key, 'cipher-algo=aes256');
$$;
```

Hope it's helpful :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting `ERROR:  Wrong key or corrupt data` at all times, should I maybe convert the key or the value to something?